# PYOMO: Operation on sets of abstract model

Tags: python, model, set, abstract, pyomo

I want to operate on abstract sets. But it dosen't work.

```py
from pyomo.environ import *
m = AbstractModel()
m.A = Set(initialize=[0,1,2])
m.B = Set(initialize=[0])
m.C = m.A-m.B
instance = m.create_instance()
for c in instance.C.value:
    print(c)
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you told to Qi Chen, here is a working example of your code if you used the AbstractModel formulation. The thing, with abstract models, is that it doesn't do much more than delay the iniatilazion of your model into a concrete model. So, it *knows* what sets is going to be used, but it has no way of knowing its content until you initialize it. For example, it knows that param `p` use the set `s` as a domain, but there is no way of knowing what are the values of `p` and the elements of `s`.

That being said, what you are trying to do is populationg your `m.C` set from unititialized sets `m.a` and `m.b`. I stand with Qi Chen, ConcreteModels are just the best option for you. However, here are three ways of using AbstractModels.

**Option 1**
Here you populate your `m.C` set *after* initializing your model. `create_instance()` basically turn your abstract model into a concrete model, by populating it. It returns the corresponding `ConcreteModel`. This way, you have a sufficient `AbstractModel` (remember, `AbstractModel` doesn't need to have populated sets, only to know which sets are being used). So, the following code populates your `m.C` set in a `ConcreteModel`, after it has been initialized:

```
m = AbstractModel()
m.A = Set(initialize=[0, 1, 2])
m.B = Set(initialize=[0])
m.C = Set()
instance = m.create_instance() # Here instance becomes your ConcreteModel
instance.C = instance.A - instance.B # The equivalent of line "m.C = m.A-m.B" but with your ConcreteModel
for c in instance.C:
    print(c)
```

**Option 2**
Here, since you seem to know what are the content of your sets, you can define it before even making your `AbstractModel`. This is just a reminder that each set is usually initalized with a Python `list` or `set`. So, just create your sets first (this time using Python's built-in sets), at the moment of the definition of your model' Sets. Here is the code:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
# Define the content of your model' Sets using built-in set
A = {0,1,2}
B = {0}
C = A - B

# You have all you need now to continue
m = AbstractModel()
m.A = Set(initialize=A)
m.B = Set(initialize=B)
m.C = Set(initialize=C)
instance = m.create_instance()
for c in instance.C:
    print(c)
```

But, again, since your sets are already defined, what I just showed you is just a fancier, harder way of creating a `ConcreteModel`, since basically, it does the same thing, that is to create a model with populated values and sets.

**Option 3**
Using the way of Option 1 and Option 2, you will not be able to change the elements of your sets afterward. For example, the following code

```
from pyomo.environ import *
A = {0, 1, 2}
B = {0}
C = A - B
m = AbstractModel()
m.A = Set(initialize=A)
m.B = Set(initialize=B)
m.C = Set(initialize=C)

# Pyomo's Sets are initialized, now, let's try to change their value:
A = {4, 5, 6}
B = {4}

instance = m.create_instance()
for c in instance.C:
    print(c)
```

will still prints

```
1
2
```

even if we tried to print

```
5
6
```

That's a major inconvenient, especially when we try to use the `AbstractModel` class as a blank model to put data in. If you want to use it this way, and IMHO, this is the only good reason to use an `AbstractModel`, then you should consider having a read on this page: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_abstractmodels/data/index.html and then, skip to this page: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_abstractmodels/data/raw_dicts.html , where it shows you an example of how to populate a blank `AbstractModel` from data, in this case, the data is provided in form of a Python dictionary. They say, in the first link I showed you, that it is not the only way of providing data to the model, but it has a complete working example in there.

The main idea would be to build your project as following:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
A = {0, 1, 2}
B = {0}

m = AbstractModel()
m.A = Set()
m.B = Set()
m.C = Set()

# ...

# Let's suppose you have completed your AbstractModel here (Params, Vars, Constraints and so on). 
# This is the part where you put your data into a dictionary. 
data = {None: {
    'A': {None: A},
    'B': {None: B},
    'C': {None: A - B}
}}

# And here is the part where you initialize your model:
instance = m.create_instance(data)
for c in instance.C:
    print(c)
```

There exist other ways of importing data to your model, but this is just to show you an easy example.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful and detailed answer. In particular the last section solved the problem well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model that way, you should use ConcreteModel and skip needing the create instance line. Your model and instance would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right it works with a ConcreteModel. But i need to model with subsets by using AbstactModels.

Comment: Subsets should still work with ConcreteModel. Is there a reason you need to use Abstract?

Comment: I know that subsets work with ConcreteModels. But i need to work with AbstractModels.

Answer (score -1):

So maybe i should say what is my motivation. I want to define a Constraint based on the subset m.C inside my AbstractModel like

```
def rule_name(m, c):
    return something depends on c
m.rule_name = Constraint(m.C, rule=rule_name)
```

Comment: Ishh, it sounds like a separated question. You should consider opening a new one for this, since building your constraint is absolutely not the same problem as your 'NoneType' error.  It litterally seems like two separated issues here. Try fixing the first one and come back to us with your new question if you still need. BTW, I suggest you to avoid commenting in "answers" spaces here, Stack Overflows mods are very strict about that, since it is not a forum style website, but a question-answer site.

Comment: However, it seems like a detail to add to your question anyway. So you could edit it. Just be careful, here, your original question was about your NoneType error, so it would be wrong to change it to "How can I build my constraint". But I agree, this can be a pertinent information. Altough, it is easy to guess that you want to add constraints and other important stuff in your model, like variables, objective functions, parameters and so on. Just be careful since this website rather see many little questions to a large problem than many little problems in a big question. Take care

Comment: Thank you for the advices. I will follow them.