# Pyomo: Redefinition of a Set

Tags: pyomo

The code below describes an abstract model in which the set J is defined by the parameter j_min.  After instantiating the model, I'd like to be able to update the parameter j_min, and have the set J updated accordingly.  However, this doesn't work, as demonstrated by the code below.  Even after I update j_min, the set J remains unchanged.

```
# Import the necessary libraries
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

# Create an abstract model
m = AbstractModel()

# Specify the minimum index
m.j_min = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers, mutable=True, initialize=1)

# Construct the set of j indices
m.J = RangeSet(m.j_min, m.j_min + 2)

# Declare the variables
m.x = Var(m.J, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Declare the objective function
def objRule(m):

    return sum(m.x[j] for j in m.J)

m.obj = Objective(rule=objRule)

# Instantiate the model
i = m.create_instance()

# Print out the elements of the set J
print('Before updating j_min, the members of the set J are:')
for j in i.J:
    print(str(j))

# Reset the parameter values (supposedly)
i.j_min = 5

# Print out the elements of the set J
print('After updating j_min, the members of the set J are:')
for j in i.J:
    print(str(j))
```

Anyone have any pro-tips on how I can achieve the desired effect?

Comment: This reminds me of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552809/pyomo-operation-on-sets-of-abstract-model where I gave a fully detailed answer on why you should use ConcreteModel for this at first, and if you are absolutely sure that you want to use an AbstractModel, how to do this.

Comment: Plus, it seems like you didn't update the set `i.J` in your example. When you created your set, parameters `m.j_min` and `m.j_min + 2` are provided as value, not as a reference. Plus, `m.j_min` is not the same as `i.j_min` because `m.j_min` will remain the same no matter what is the value of `i.j_min`.

Comment: Can you advise me on how I would update the set `i.J`?

Comment: Where do you want it to be updated in your code?

Comment: Just below the comment `# Reset the parameter values (supposedly)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
# Reset the parameter values (supposedly)
i.j_min = 5
i.J = RangeSet(i.j_min, i.j_min + 2)
```

If `i.J` is defined as the range of values above `i.j_min`, then when changing `i.j_min`, you have to change the set `i.J` also, to make things coherent. If you don't you will get this:

```
i.j_min = 5
i.J = [1,2,3]
```

And that is because python is a procedural language, not a symbolic one. That means that changing the value of something that defines something else will have no impact on the definition of the dependant object, unless you specifically change it latter in the code.

That also means that whenever you do something like this in a model, it is a good idea to think about how your code will remember to change it even if you forgot, and that's where good programming habits comes handy. In this line of toughts, putting this in a function that takes care of remembering to update the dependent object can become very usefull.